# Is it possible to use Glide with the AppIntro library?

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am using the [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) library for an app in Android and I want to download the images from my `Firebase Storage`, I am familiar with `Glide` and I have actually used it. The problem is that I haven't found any solution on how to access the `ImageView` so that I can use the `into()` function from Glide, and I haven't found a way to get the picture as a `Drawable` resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible .... But you will need to implement your firebase functionality within Fragments.

> You can set your own fragments in APP INTRO LIBRARY with your own
>   views and functionalities.